# By using the properties of definite integrals, evaluate $\int_0^{\pi}\frac{x}{1+\sin x}dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

> By using the properties of definite integrals, evaluate $\int_0^{\pi}\frac{x}{1+\sin x}dx$.

My attempt:

(Using the property $\int_0^{2a}f(x)dx=\int_0^a(f(x)+f(2a-x))dx$)

$$\int_0^{2\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{x}{1+\sin x}dx=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\frac{x}{1+\sin x}+\frac{\pi-x}{1+\sin x})dx$$$$=\pi\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac1{1+\sin x}dx=\pi\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1-\sin x}{\cos^2x}dx$$$$=\pi\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\sec^2x-\sec x\tan x)dx=\pi[\tan x-\sec x]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

Now I am stuck. I understand there might be other ways of solving it, but what's wrong in my method? Why am I not getting the answer?

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi Thanks. Did that.

Comment: Maybe $1-\sin x=0$ for $x=\pi/2$ and so you're dividing by zero when multiply and divide by that expression?

Comment: Your computation is correct. Note that $$\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}(\tan x-\sec x)=\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin x-1}{\cos x}\stackrel{\text{L'Hôpital}}=\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos x}{(-\sin x)}=0.$$ So the singularity of your antiderivative at $x=\pi/2$ is removable, and the answer just works.

Comment: @TitoEliatron Thanks. I think this is it. Can you add that as answer? I'll accept that.

Comment: @SangchulLee Oh nice. I didn't know we could do like that too. Thanks.

Comment: @aarbee, Another idea is to use the identity $$\tan x-\sec x=-\frac{\cos x}{1+\sin x},$$ which has the same effect of removing the "artificial" singularity at $x=\pi/2$ but in a more elementary way.

Comment: @SangchulLee that's even better, thanks.

Comment: Could you add a step of how you got the first line of your solution? I can somewhat see how it works, but I don't see the exact step that allowed for the rewriting of the $\pi - x$ to be valid. But it is creative and looking forward to an explanation.

Comment: @dc3rd I have edited the post.

Comment: Thanks. for the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1-\sin x=0$ for $x=\pi/2$ and so you're dividing by zero when multiply and divide by that expression.

Comment: We're also multiplying by $0$, so this doesn't quite identify the problem.  In fact, we are multiplying by something that is constantly $1$ where it is defined and can be extended continuously to $1$, so if we take a limit to evaluate the antiderivative is is approaches this singularity, we will obtain the correct answer where it seems we are dividing by zero.

Answer (score 4):

Your final integral is an [improper integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral), so you do not evaluate the antiderivative you obtain at the endpoints, you take limits approaching the endpoints.

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} (\tan x - \sec x) &= -1  \\
\lim_{x \rightarrow (\pi/2)^-} (\tan x - \sec x) &= 0  \text{.}
\end{align*}

So you obtain $\pi(0--1) = \pi$, which is the correct answer.  (The first limit is not actually necessary, since the antiderivative is continuous at $x = 0$.)

Comment: +1. When you say 'The first limit is not actually necessary', are you implying that whenever we encounter $\infinity$ after putting limits, we can treat that as zero?

Comment: @aarbee : No.  I've just edited in the observation that the antiderivative is continuous at $x = 0$, so no use of a limit is needed -- just evaluate at that endpoint.

Comment: Oh, okay, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, I like to try to change sine to cosine and then tackle it by the properties of odd and even functions.

First of all,  I use the substitution $y=\dfrac{\pi}{2}-x,$ then

$$
\begin{aligned}
I &=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\frac{\pi}{2}-y}{1+\cos y} d y \\
&=\frac{\pi}{2} \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{d y}{1+\cos y}-\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{y}{1+\cos y} d y \\
&=\frac{\pi}{2} \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{d y}{1+\cos y} \quad \text { (By the fact that } \frac{y}{1+\cos y} \textrm{ is odd.}) \\
&=\frac{\pi}{2} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sec ^{2} \frac{y}{2} d y \\
&=\pi\left[\tan \frac{y}{2}\right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \\
&=\pi
\end{aligned}
$$
:|D Wish you enjoy the proof!